# Using sklearn's LabelEncoder on a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, data-mining

If I have a dataframe, say df, and if

```
df["levels"] = pd.Series(["low", "low", "med", "low", "med", "high"])
```

Is there a way to change this to be:

```
df["levels"] = pd.Series([0,0,1,0,1,2])
```

I've tried using preprocessing.LabelEncoder() to transform this, but it simply collapses into [0,1,2]. I know I can just do this with for loops, but it would be great if there were some tool already out there to do this Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean it collapses? Please show your code

Answer (score 1):

There is two way ..
op1 `category`

```
pd.Series(["low", "low", "med", "low", "med", "high"]).astype('category').cat.codes
Out[1454]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    1
4    2
5    0
dtype: int8
```

op2 `factorize`

```
pd.factorize(pd.Series(["low", "low", "med", "low", "med", "high"]))[0]
Out[1455]: array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you used `sklearn` to encode your column of strings, since that was not included in the original post. However, you can used the `LabelEncoder()` following the steps below

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.levels.unique())
df.levels = le.transform(df.levels)
```

---

```
   levels
0       1
1       1
2       2
3       1
4       2
5       0
```

Comment: Would I use: le.fit(df.levels.unique()) or le.fit(df["levels"].unique())?

Comment: @Ammastaro, you can use either